# Fastest weighted random algorithm in Scala?

Tags: algorithm, scala, optimization

I'm writing a server-side module for a Scala based project, and I need to find the fastest way to perform a weighted random number generation between some `Int` weights. The method should be as fastest as possible since it will be called very often.

Now, this is what I came up with:

```
import scala.util.Random

trait CumulativeDensity {

  /** Returns the index result of a binary search to find @n in the discrete
    * @cdf array.
    */
  def search(n: Int, cdf: Array[Int]): Int = {
    val i: Int = cdf.indexWhere(_ != 0)
    if (i<0 | n<=cdf(i))
      i
    else
      search(n-cdf(i), {cdf.update(i,0); cdf})
  }

  /** Returns the cumulative density function (CDF) of @list (in simple terms,
    * the cumulative sums of the weights).
    */
  def cdf(list: Array[Int]) = list.map{
    var s = 0;
    d => {s += d; s}
  }
}
```

And I define the main method with this piece of code:

```
def rndWeighted(list: Array[Int]): Int =
  search(Random.nextInt(list.sum + 1), cdf(list))
```

However, it still isn't fast enough. Is there any kind of black magic that makes unnecessary to iterate over the list since its start (libraries, built-ins, heuristics)?

**EDIT:** this is the final version of the code (much faster now):

```
def search(n: Int, cdf: Array[Int]): Int = {
  if (n > cdf.head)
    1 + search(n-cdf.head, cdf.tail)
  else
    0
}
```

Comment: Do you want to draw many samples from one distribution or is it really just one sample for each? If you want many samples and the sum of weights isn't too large, you can just populate an array with repeated values according to the weights, and draw from a random index into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `cdf.update(i,0)` and passing the entire `cdf` back to    `cdf.indexWhere(_ != 0)` in the next recursive call, consider

```
cdf.splitAt(i)
```

and passing only the elements on the *right* of `i`, so in the following recursion, `indexWhere` scans a smaller array. Note the array size being monotonic decreasing at each recursive call ensures termination.